# Adding ToolTip to WPF shapes

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-controls, tooltip, shapes

How do I add different tooltips to the shapes in the WPF zoomable canvas discussed in the msdn blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items.aspx ?

I tried adding a tooltip using binding, but that doesn't seem to work. The shapes are added as list box items.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Some simple code illustrating the problem would probably help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example is nothing like how I would have programmed it, but nevertheless it works. To add ToolTip's to that example do the following:

#### XAML

Add ToolTip to this Style

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
   ...
   <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding toolTip}"/>
</Style>
```

#### Code Behind

Add toolTip reference in GridLikeItemsSource.cs

```
public object this[int i]
{
   ...
   var height = rand.Next(50, 100);
   var toolTip = "ToolTip";
   ...
   return new { top, left, width, height, data, brush, i, toolTip };
}
```

Comment: I was adding tooltip to the Path object and it was not working. This worked. But the problem I'm having is similar to curves in the MSDN zoomable canvas, I have lot of intersecting curves and due to the bounding box (which appears on selecting the curve), only tooltip of 1 object is displayed (the one which is on top). Would you possibly know how to remove that bounding box thing?

Comment: What go you mean by bounding box?

Comment: I see you opened a new question for that comment. You should mark this one as the answer in the meantime